# How to upgrade intel-microcode used by iucode-tool?

Tags: 15.10, intel

I am running 15.10 and installed the intel-microcode package.
The actual microcode being installed is labelled "20150121", while the [Intel website](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25512/Linux-Processor-Microcode-Data-File) offers "20151106".

What's the command (or procedure) needed in order to install newest update by Intel?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can download the latest intel-microcode package .deb from the latest Ubuntu distro, and just install it.  This will work as long as the first digit of the Debian/Ubuntu version number of the intel-microcode package is the same.

Also, sometimes it just doesn't make sense to keep updating older versions of Ubuntu with new microcode packages, because the kernel and other drivers on old Ubuntu don't really support your (newer) processor properly, anyway.  In that case, the recommended is to switch to a newer version of Ubuntu itself (which will also come with a newer intel-microcode package).

That said, every so often the Intel group in Canonical will request that older versions of the distro should also get the newest intel-microcode package.

Comment: I was wishing to know how to use files from Intel distribution, though. Your remarks make sense, anyway.

Comment: There are instructions on how to use the intel data files in the README documentation of either intel-microcode or iucode-tool, they're installed at /usr/share/doc/<package name>.   But, basically, do this:  "iucode_tool -K /tmp/microcode.dat /lib/firmware/intel-ucode", where /tmp/microcode.dat is the file you downloaded from Intel.  After that, use "update-initramfs -u" to update the initramfs, and reboot.  You must be root to use these commands.

Comment: That's the right answer. Why not editing yours?

Comment: By the way, you need to clean /lib/firmware/intel-ucode as the tool won't overwrite any existing file!